# Problem with loading MASS package using library. What is the solution?

Tags: r, rscript

I am trying to load MASS package with this code:

```
install.packages("MASS")
library(MASS)
```

But R is showing this error:

```
> install.packages("MASS")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("MASS")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/MASS_7.3-55.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1189524 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeGnfs7\downloaded_packages
> library(MASS)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package ‘MASS’ version 7.3.54 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘MASS’ is imported by ‘mlogit’ so cannot be unloaded
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘MASS’ was built under R version 4.1.2
```

Comment: `mlogit` depends on `MASS` and it's old version is loaded. Restarting R should solve it. Or try again after `unloadNamespace('mlogit')`.